# Solve the equation $\sin(\theta) + c\sin(2\theta) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Assuming $0 \geq \theta (2\pi)$, how does one solve an equation of the form
$$
\sin(\theta) + c\sin(2\theta) = 0?
$$
More generally, how does one solve an equation of the form
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n c_k\sin(k\theta) = 0?
$$
A reference to a standard text is more than enough. Thanks!

Comment: For the first question, you can just write $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ and then factorize.

Comment: Consider the Chebyshev polynomials to reduce simplify the latter expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use that $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Comment: Of course! Thanks.

Comment: For the next step $sin(x) + c_2 sin(2x) + c_3 sin(3x) = 0$?

Comment: use that $$\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$$

Comment: . ..  and so on with the multiple angle formulas. Thanks!

Comment: nice, another Problem was solved!